# Can I use two identical pronouns to indicate different people or stuff in one sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, personal-pronouns

For instance, I would like to speak as follows:

> The black ants like to eat the liquid produced by aphids. In order to
>   earn **their** own livings, the black ants help guard and feed
>   **their** young. As a result, **they** can take **them** as a reliable source of food.

Can I say that if I do not create any ambiguity?

Comment: Of course you can, and of course it creates ambiguity.  Is it any different in your own native language?

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, you remind me of my native language. In Chinese, the pronounciations of "he" and "she" and "it" are the same, so we usually do not say them in one sentence. I think that issue is similar to this one. So what you mean is to use their real names instead of the same pronouns to avoid ambiguity, right?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but some of the time it's obvious what the pronouns refer to by their location in the sentence.  In your example I can tell which pronouns refer to which subjects, but it would be easier to read if you used the nouns, or some kind of referential description.